# Data Science Drag & Drop Tools (Python+Anaconda)

Tags: python, data-analysis, drag-drop

I am looking for a web-based drag & drop tool (open source) similar to Azure ML studio that can be on-premise and can support cross-cloud deployments.

If there isn't anything close, looking for suggestions on how to get started with how to build a "Drag & Drop" interface in python that can run pandas/sklearn code snippets in the back end.